# What is an active request for Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

In Tomcat's documentation, the definition of system property `org.apache.catalina.session.
StandardSession.ACTIVITY_CHECK` states the following:

> If this is true, Tomcat will track the number of
>   active requests for each session. When
>   determining if a session is valid, any session
>   with at least one active request will always be
>   considered valid.

I find no definition of an "active request" in the docs.  Does that mean "not idle" in the sense that the request is not older than `minIdleSwap`?

Also, in the quote above "valid session" seems to mean "active session".  Are these two terms synonymous for Tomcat?  I would think that "valid" means that the session has neither expired nor been explicitly invalidated.  That is not related to activity.

May I please get some guidance on the terminology (active request, active session, valid session)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"active request" means a request that Tomcat is currently processing.

"valid session" means a session that has not expired.

"active session" (if used) means the same as "valid session".

The Servlet spec defines the last accessed time of a session as the last time a request was **received** that was associated with the session. If you have very long running requests and short session timeouts you could have the situation where a session times out while a request associated with it is still being processed. This isn't as unreasonable as it sounds. Consider large file downloads / uploads over slow links.

`StandardSession.ACTIVITY_CHECK` was added to avoid this edge case.

If `StandardSession.ACTIVITY_CHECK` is set, Tomcat will never expire a session if there is at least one request being processed that is associated with the session.

Comment: Truly an edge case that explains it.  Could have not figured this out on my own. I'd suggest adding this to the docs.